# $\wedge(R^{\oplus d})=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We have for all $M$, $N$ $R$-modules $\wedge_R (M\oplus N)=\wedge_R M\otimes\wedge_R N$. So what wrong with that calculus:
$$ \wedge_R R^{\oplus d} =(\wedge_R R)^{\otimes d}= 0 ^{\otimes d}=0 $$
I write $\wedge_R R= 0$ because for all $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in R$
$$ a_1\wedge a_2\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k=(a_1 a_2\ldots a_k) 1\wedge 1\wedge\ldots \wedge 1=0$$
What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bigwedge R \neq 0$ : $R$ is a submodule of it (twice, actually, if $\bigwedge$ is the full exterior algebra, there is $\bigwedge^0 R \oplus \bigwedge^1 R$, and both of these are isomorphic to $R$)

Comment: Clear! My reasoning on $a_1\wedge\ldots\wedge a_k$ don't work with $k=0$ or $k=1$

Answer (score 1):

The formula
$$
\Lambda_R^\bullet(M\oplus N)\cong\Lambda_R^\bullet M\otimes\Lambda_R^\bullet N
$$
of graded $R$-modules means
$$
\Lambda_R^p(M\oplus N)\cong\bigoplus_{j=0}^p\Lambda_R^j M\otimes\Lambda_R^{p-j} N
$$

Going back to your example.  The graded module $\Lambda^\bullet_R R$ is
$$
\Lambda_R^d R=\begin{cases}
R & d=0,1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and so
$$
\Lambda_R^\bullet(R^{\oplus d})=\bigotimes^{d}\Lambda_R^\bullet R
$$
is
$$
=\begin{cases}
R^{\oplus\binom{d}{k}} & \text{degree }k\in\{0,1,\dots,d\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: You mean $R^{\bigoplus\binom{{d}}{k}}$?

Comment: yes, corrected.